# Fingertip-covering picks for fingerstyle guitar

Tags: guitar, picks

I've seen a couple of videos in which a fingerstyle guitar player appears to have solid white, maybe plastic, picks covering the last segment of his finger.

I haven't been able to find these at the music stores I've been to.  All I've seen there are metal fingerpicks and plastic thumb picks.

Does anyone know what these picks are?

An example can be seen at about 2:47 to 2:50 in [this video of the group Mandolin Orange](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOHkyZ62jjQ).  I've also seen them on Steve Baughman.

Comment: As far I'm aware, they're just called fingerpicking picks. I picked up a set from my local guitar store not too long ago - they aren't uncommon. A cursory search for "fingerpicking picks" has brought up numerous online shopping options. I think mine specifically are made by Stagg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finger picks and thumb pics.  They make them in metal, plastic, and just about every other material they use to make pics.  I am surprised that you couldn't find them in the music store.  I have a few sets, got them at Guitar Center.  As suggested you can find them by googling "finger picks" and I see them on Amazon and every other online store.  Sam Ash and Guitar Center would have them.  If you really want them I would go to a store and try some out.  The fit can be an issue if you've never tried them before and you don't want to trow money away.

Comment: Yeah the stores I've checked (in Vancouver BC) have finger picks and thumb picks, but all the finger picks I've been able to find are metal.  I've got some of those, but don't really use them.  The ones I was asking about seem to be quite different from what I've got.  Yeah, I don't really want to just buy them online because I want to try them on first to get the right fit.  Thanks.

Comment: It surprises me that you cannot find plastic.  One of my students had the opposite problem, found plastic easily but not metal.  She has very small fingers and could not adjust the plastic to fit her fingers.

Answer (score 2):

I searched for "finger picks small" on eBay and found some plastic ones, don't know if it answer your question, here's the [link](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=finger%20picks%20small&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_osacat=0&_odkw=finger%20picks&LH_TitleDesc=0)